# Can 'aircrafts' be automagically changed to 'aircraft'?

Tags: feature-request, editing, moderation

From time to time someone's blood pressure spikes when the plural 'aircrafts' is used in the Aviation forum. Would it be possible to implement a simple script in the system to delete the superfluous s's?
(Interesting: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46824/why-does-the-incorrect-plural-aircrafts-seem-to-be-occurring-more-often)

Answer (score 7):

Nope.

It's not feasible to scan and change user input to the site - if we were to do it for `aircrafts` people would want it done for `supposably`, `irregardless`, [`alot`](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html), and many other words that cause people to twitch and foam at the mouth.

We could blacklist the word `aircrafts` from the site (prohibiting its use anywhere on Aviation Stack Exchange), but that seems a *little* extreme: Among other things it would present users with a very unfriendly and confusing "The word `aircrafts` is not permitted on this site!" message, which is a really lousy first impression to make on people just because their grammar is cringe-worthy.

If it really bothers you that much feel free to edit the questions to correct the poor spelling/grammar - this is a very minor edit, but I personally would approve the changes as it substantially improves readability (or at least reduces my blood pressure).

Comment: +1 just for the alot link

Comment: Wow, I've never received a "The word is not allowed message" anywhere on SE. I've gotta try harder.

Comment: @Dan Try posting a link to lmgtfy - it's banned network-wide.

Comment: @voretaq7 http://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+plane+flies

Comment: @Dan: Hmm, I thought those were vulnerable to a single not-constructive flag (i.e., would be auto-deleted), but apparently not.

Comment: @Dan Only works in posts (Q/A) IIRC, and may not be active on Meta though I think it is. :)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Someone (a mod) has to validate the flag (and in this case I cleared it without deleting the comment since it's semi-relevant to the discussion).

Comment: @voretaq7: Used to be (still is, I think), certain comment strings would be auto-deleted with a very low flag threshold, no mod intervention required. But I guess [this was never one of those](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238835/what-is-the-se-version-of-seven-dirty-words).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah I'm not sure how that logic works (or whether it's enabled network-wide vs. site-by-site with specific lists of strings to check for) - I'm inclined to think it's not enabled here, though we've not had any of the "naughty words" show up in a comment as far as I know :)